# Is there a feminine equivalent to the adjective "avuncular"?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms, gender-positive

My brief researches only bring up the word "auntlike" to render the feminine equivalent of avuncular. Surely, though, and given the etymology of "aunt" [ < Latin *amita* -father's sister, old feminine past participle of *amāre* to love, i.e., beloved ], there must be a more lyrical word to hand.

Comment: What properties of 'avuncular' do you want in the feminine version? And do those properties form a concept that are associated with lots of aunt-like people?

Comment: The properties are commensurate with the sex: warm, loving and protective -plus good with presents at Christmas and birthdays! [Sorry to sound irreverent, but I'm not an accredited sociologist.]

Comment: I suppose you will ask for a feminine equivalent for "nepotism" next...

Comment: Touché, GE, (or should I say 'toccata'?)

Comment: [The Columbia Guide to Standard American English](http://metro-natshar-31-71.brain.net.pk/articles/_1gjsNMT43.pdf) says in its entry for **avuncular**: *A curiosity: English has no similar adjective to deal with matters or qualities typical of an aunt: auntish and auntlike are about as close as we can come.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers And the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114954) disagrees with that assessment. See the full entry posted below. See what I mean about getting you a sub? :)

Comment: @tchrist haha well you're quite right that unless you copy it out for me, I can't see the OED details. And being somewhat impecunious these days, I ain't gonna get that sub from my own resources. But I'd already formed the impression from instances in GoogleBooks that it's not exactly a "kosher" word, and [this reference](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=42PMCiOVFq8C&pg=PT144&dq=materteral&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MtI_T9X4L8Gg0QW_t7mPDw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=materteral&f=false) seems to confirm my understanding.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can’t see your reference: it’s all blanked-out.  I copied out the complete OED3 entry below.  ᴘs: Sorry to hear about your cows. :)

Comment: ...and I quite like [this one](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jsXisul8pqwC&pg=PT107&dq=materteral&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MtI_T9X4L8Gg0QW_t7mPDw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=materteral&f=false) saying "materteral" is *"stuck on the slag heap of familial words that no-one knows or cares about any more"*. Alongside [consobrinal](http://www.latin-dictionary.org/consobrinus) for "like a cousin".

Comment: @tchrist: Oh. Well I do sometime register for free online access to various things - perhaps that's why you can't follow my link. Can you view the details by clicking on the link "Totally Weird and Wonderful Words" from [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22by+the+word+materteral%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)? If not perhaps we could follow this up in chat if/when you have time?

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, it says it’s unavailable for viewing, or that I’ve reached my limit — and I’ve never looked at it before. However, I *can* read [Michael Quinion’s blog posting](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-mat2.htm) regarding *materteral*. Being a Briton, he gives only the ʀᴘ pronunciation, whereas the ᴏᴇᴅ gives the GenAm one, too. I wonder whether non-ʀᴘ speakers in Britain (say, Scots for example) take umbrage that the dictionary uses ‘Brit.’ to mean ʀᴘ.  Well, or mostly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2542/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-tchrist)

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for entertaining responses. I have to surmise that uncles must have felt more fun than aunts, who bore more with their sisters’ responsibilities in a matrilineal age and society.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deriving from your own explanation in the OP, the natural choice would be ***amicular***.

I do not seem to find any dictionary entries. Need to see why.

Preliminary:
[Book Doctor Gwen](http://bookdoctorgwen.blogspot.in/2010/01/ege.html)  : 92 Feminine and Masculine Word Pairs
Feminine term / Masculine term /// neutral or inclusive term
4. amicular* / avuncular
(*Terms that are slang or recently coined.)

[Contemporary Pragmatism - Google Books Result](http://books.google.com/books?id=YrBMClqkrNwC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=%22amicular%22&source=bl&ots=gjgQ_-hg1c&sig=jQPv4aEVbvFPd8T8uH2uaGIefwk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XEM_T6KjNsSqrAegrrzJBw&sqi=2&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBw)
books.google.com/books?isbn=9042018445...
John R. Shook, Paulo Ghiraldelli - 2004 - Philosophy - 200 pages
*... be offered as amicular advice to discourse generation researchers, along the lines of the earlier 'Don't ask for the meaning; ask for the use', ...*

Comment: Your answer is a thing of beauty, Kris -thank you! I can't imagine it catching on quickly, but I'll use it regularly now. (And hey, remember when they said bringing "misandry" into the working language was an uphill battle!) EDIT: interesting to see Gwen has it as "... recently coined" -she's quick!

Comment: The right answer is ***materteral***, from Latin *materteral*, for one’s mother’s aunt. It’s only been around for going on 200 years though. *Avuncular* is also one’s mother’s brother in origin. There didn’t appear to be father’s-side terms, although we don’t usually make that distinction in English. If we did, then something from *patruus* for one’s father’s brother and from *amita* for one’s father’s sister might make sense. Then again, only matrilineal relations are certain. That’s why one’s sisterson had a special honor in ancient societies: he was more surely related to you than your own.

Comment: @tchrist: You mean one's aunt on the mother's side, (*maternal aunt*) not "one’s mother’s aunt." I believe.

Comment: @tchrist: 'tanticular' has also been proposed (but not as seriously. 'amicular' would also correspond more directly to 'amita'. Re 'ancient' societies, well, pretty much every permutation has existed in some society somewhere and more (Amazon rain forest, German tribes, New Guinea highlands, etc).

Comment: This doesn't look right. The *-cular* at the end of "avuncular" is not a suffix. The word is composed of the root *avuncul-* + the suffix *-ar* (a variant of *-al* generally used when there is an L nearby). "Amicular" therefore looks like it is derived from *amicula* (which apparently meant "mistress" in Latin!) or *amiculus.*  Since the actual word you're using is *amita,* I would think you should form the adjective as *amit-* + *al,* "amital."

Comment: There is no word with the same usage. avuncular is used to mean kindly like an uncle. There is no distaff side ***with equivalent usage***. Who says: She so materteral? No one. The existence of a word is not usage of it.

Answer (score 10):

The correct answer, courtesy of the *Oxford English Dictionary*, is the word [***materteral***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114954), whose entry I give here *in toto*:

> **Pronunciation**: Brit.  /məˈtəːtərl̩/ , U.S.  /məˈtərdər(ə)l/
>
> **Etymology**:  < classical Latin *mātertera*  maternal aunt ( < *māter* **mother** *n.<sup>1</sup>*  + *‑tera* , feminine of *‑ter*, suffix forming nouns) + **‑al** *suffix<sup>1</sup>*.
>
> *humorous. rare.*
>
> Characteristic or typical of an aunt. Cf. **avuncular** *adj*.
>
> - 1823        W. Taylor in *Monthly Rev.* 102 447       With maternal and materteral anxiety.
> - 1867        J. N. Taylor *Spindrift* 6       You can picture the stately materteral form—A full-blown Atè, big with doom!

The proper citation for that entry is:

> > materteral, adj.
> >
> > Third edition, March 2001; online version December 2011. < http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114954 >; accessed 18 February 2012. An entry for this word was first included in *New English Dictionary*, 1905.

Comment: Thanks for your answers (here & in the post above), tchrist. I love the labyrinths of etymology, but I confess the coloration of this particular word's has me bemused. One source calls *amicular* "slang or recently coined" -here disproved. Your *materteral* [like a snoring terrapin, maybe?] is "humorous. rare". I only wanted to say that I marvel at the contradictory messages sent in parallel: that matrilineage is an incontrovertible truth, and that the English words needed to illuminate that fact are either non-existent or fatuous.

Comment: @fortunate1 Well... *avuncular* and *materteral* (“What’s that y’all’re sayin’ ’bout mah turtle there, eh?”) are both from your mother’s brother and sister, not your father’s, so I’d say in origin they’re matrilineal.  It’s really too bad English seems to have finally lost *eam*, *eme*, *an eme* > *a neme* for your mother’s brother; that is, for your maternal uncle. One doesn’t need Latin that way.

Answer (score 1):

While their lyrical nature is subjective, [dictionaries list](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aunt) both *aunt-like* as well as *auntly* as suitable adjectives.