# What do you call someone who gets along with children?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phrase-requests, colloquialisms

What do you call someone who gets along with children/babies?

A simple example:

> He is such a ________, he makes all children smile.

A single word noun would be ideal but a phrase is acceptable also. There might be a colloquial word or phrase too.

---

For example, there is a phrase ***good mixer*** which means someone who can get along with everyone [[See](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mixer): second meaning of mixer]. So, what we are looking for is almost like a subtype of this characteristic.

There are words like *likeable* or *easygoing* but they are too general.

The closest word I could find is ***avuncular*** but it does not sound that suitable for this usage. I have never used this word in this way.

> Kind and friendly towards a younger or less experienced person: *he was avuncular, reassuring, and trustworthy*
>
> [[oxforddictionaries]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/avuncular)

Also, I'm not sure if we can use avuncular as a gender neutral word for this sense. [Because it is a masculine word for its anthropological sense]. It seems like there isn't a common word as a feminine version. *Amicular* and *materteral* is proposed in this previous ELU question: [Is there a feminine equivalent to the adjective “avuncular”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58383/is-there-a-feminine-equivalent-to-the-adjective-avuncular)

Comment: The most common phrasing in current usage is "He is *good with children*". Nice find with with *avuncular*, though.

Comment: Specifically a man or both men and women? I think avuncular is best, although that also can be interpreted as "uncle-like".

Comment: @Tim: Both. a person.

Comment: "S/he's such a softie,...", is sometimes said with affection and evokes images of grandparents and favourite aunts and uncles who *spoil* the smaller children in the family.

Comment: *Avuncular* is very specialised. It means 'like an uncle'. It is perfectly possible to be good with children without being 'avuncular'.

Comment: If don't mind being colloquial, saying that someone is "a kid person" is the good-with-children equivalent of calling someone who's good with people "a people person."

Answer (score 3):

Maternal and Paternal work in some cases.

> [Maternal](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+maternal)
> -- (of feelings) typical of a caring mother; motherly.
>
> [Paternal](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+paternal)
> -- of or appropriate to a father.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **avuncular**. Here is part of a discussion of the term at [Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com):

> *Avuncular* derives from the Latin noun *avunculus*, which translates as "maternal uncle," but since at least the 1830s English speakers have used "avuncular" to refer to uncles from either side of the family or even to individuals who are simply uncle-like in character or behavior.

Comment: Avuncular really doesn't work, or rather it's a word for one way of getting along with kids, out of many possible ones.  For instance, I get along with kids not because I'm the least bit avuncular, but because I never bothered to grow up :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[pied piper](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pied-piper)*

> a person who entices others to follow him [*Collins*]

This term has a bit of a dark undertone, often suggesting *... follow him to their doom.*

A common, but somewhat mundane phrase is *he has [a way](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way) [or such a way] with children.* The specifics of *way* are left unstated, but it is universally understood to be

> ability to get along well or perform well: *she has a way with kids*; *a way with words* [*Merriam-Webster*: 5.b.]

Your sentence might be rephrased

> *He has such a way with children; he makes them smile.*

Comment: In the (happy) context given by the OP, _pied piper_ is certainly not the answer. Way too sinister... :-)

Comment: "follow him to their doom" - yes, i'd say that's a *"bit of a dark undertone"*.

Comment: So I guess "pedophile" isn't a good choice either?