# What is a word to describe someone who enjoys interacting with children?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word to describe someone who enjoys interacting with children, or/and is good with kids?

Comment: Have you any research? This site asks a similar question, but there are no good answers: http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=413458

Comment: @Silenus I've googled, but there didn't seem to be a good answer. Was hoping to find a one here :)

Comment: In certain circumstances, you might say the person was ***a child at heart***.

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193782/what-do-you-call-someone-who-gets-along-with-children

Comment: A  "scout leader" or "scouter" implies someone who enjoys being with children.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **nurturer** would encompass this, although the word tends to cover a much broader kinds of relationship (e.g. nurse and patient). This also assumes a link between being "good" with kids, and "nurturing" them, and I suppose you can joke around with kids without necessarily nurturing them (like a clown).

**Paternal** or **maternal** might also fit the bill, but, again, it also depends on how someone interacts with kids.