# Equivalent of 'Avunculicide'

Tags: meaning

*Avunculicide* is the act of killing an uncle. Is there an equivalent term for the act of killing an aunt?

Comment: *Avaunticide*...?

Comment: Of related interest: *[Is there a feminine equivalent to the adjective “avuncular”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58383)*

Comment: How about for killing a cousin...once-removed...-in-law?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing that I could find, but 'matertericide' or 'amiticide' would make the most sense, depending on whether you were referring to your maternal or paternal aunt, respectively.

Latin words for paternal aunt and maternal aunt can be found [here](http://www.dl.ket.org/latin1/vocab/vocab12.htm).

Comment: Sorry--after more research, it seems to me that your original suggestion was actually the best--since the Latin source word is *matertera*, the e seems to be part of the root. Not my downvote by the way. It would be nice if you could find a source for these words.

Comment: I will add the source I used - thank you for the input, however - I, too, thought 'matertericide' looked a bit odd.

Comment: +1 'materteral' (humorous, rare) and 'materterine' (humorous nonce-word) are given in *OED Online*. 'Matertericide' is not given, but then neither is 'avunculicide'.

Comment: Many thanks - so no one can argue if I use the word amitricide !!!!!!

Comment: @RayRead They could argue: you just misspelled it. =) You should also tick cgde's answer as correct and complete.