# "Federal" is to "Federally" as "State" is to

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

If you were to say that something would be taxed by the federal government, you could say it was taxable federally (though you would more likely say it was federally taxable).

If something would instead be taxed by the state government, you could say it was state taxable, but you couldn't say it is taxable [stately](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stately). Is there a word that would fit in that same sentence structure, replacing federally?

The best I can find is [statewise](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/statewise), but I can only find a single online dictionary defining it as rare.

```
adverb
rare
With regard to the State or a state.
```

Comment: Please confirm: You are asking about AmE usage with regard to state and federal issues in reference to government/governing/governance. Is that correct, Professor Chaos?

Comment: Your problem is partly already present in your question: *federal* is an adjective while *state* is a noun. The reason you are asking apples and pears is probably that there *is no* adjective on the state level (ha!) corresponding to federal, and hence no adverb either. Your question is at the core "Federation is to federal as state is to ...".

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica state is not only a noun: "State funding was very low".  Many nouns in English can function as adjectives, fyi. And all these points to inaccurate answers just shows what people simply do not know, I'm afraid. This question stands out in that  some answers do not answer the question at all.....This is one of those oddities one gets around here.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, my question refers mostly to American government, with federal and state level authorities. I've added American-English as a tag.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.  I am truly befuddled by all the upvotes to inaccurate answers.  Really puzzling.....

Comment: As others have said, 'Federal' is an adjective, so the comparison is unfair.  That said, there is an adjectival form of 'state' corresponding to the adjectival form of 'federation'.

I wouldn't say it's a commonly used word, but here it is:

statal

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statal

That would imply that the adverbial form "should" be 'statally'.  I don't know if it has ever really been used though.  Google n-grams does not find it.

Comment: "Provincial" and move to Canada :/

Comment: @Lambie Do you mean *state* is often used as an *[attributive noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attributive_noun)*, see e.g. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/state): "noun, often attributive", like in *state government?* It would still be a noun.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I call those adjectival nouns, myself. The word functions as an adjective. People can call them attributive if they like. I don't mind. But you can't always make state into an adverb like federally is an adverb.

Comment: @Lambie Well, *attribute* is a grammatical function while *adjective* is a word form. It's a bit like the function *home* vs. the form *residential building:* Form often coincides with function, but not always.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I said adjectival. an adjectival noun.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You've seen a bunch of suggestions, but when a single word is used in this context, it's overwhelmingly ***state***.

Notice we pretty much always use "federally" with a passive verb.  Since "federal" is an adjective, we need to turn it into an adverb so that we can modify a verb. But the noun "state" has no such problem.

- Federally-insured: state-insured
- Federally-owned: state-owned
- Federally-funded: state-funded
- Federally-subsidized: state-subsidized
- Federally-recognized: state-recognized (but only in a hurry)

You didn't explicitly ask for an adverb, so this definitely answers the question as you asked it.  But you can also think of it this way: Not all adverbs end in *-ly*.

Comment: There is an old alternate use of "federally" as "generally", or "integral(ly)" but that's not what OP was asking about.

Comment: What do you mean by `(but only in a hurry)`?

Comment: @Roddy I might use the other ones in general writing, but the last one only where brevity is important.

Comment: and federally insured is fine, state insured is not.

Comment: @Lambie My state had a deposit insurance program for S&L's and we heard "state-insured" in the news a lot, especially while the program was crashing and burning.

Comment: That is adjectival. This bank account is federally insured. This bank account is insured at state level.  You must be referring to state-chartered credit unions: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/financial-institution-fails-acquired-29945.html Credit unions in states without this requirement will typically be covered by state insurance or private insurance. But "state-insured" is not a standard term.

Answer (score 14):

There are a few adverbs for governmental levels, but *stately* is not one of them.

For example, one quote in definition 2 for the entry "[federally, adv.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68926)" in the Oxford English Dictionary features *municipally*:

> 1940   Amer. Guardian 5 Apr. 4/3   The privateers never..reduce their rate unless forced to do so by public competition in the shape of **municipally** or **federally** owned [electric power] plants.

**Municipally** suggests a form of local control, like by a town or county government. In many countries, the next step up would be **provincially** or **regionally**, as this example from "[provincially, adv.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/153469)" suggests:

> 1992   J. M. Bumsted Peoples of Canada vi. 190   During the Depression, Canadians thought **regionally** or **provincially** rather than **nationally**.

I've been able to uncover no adverb for *state* that is the equivalent of *provincially* or *municipally*. Instead, I've only found articles that refer to the US levels of government - state, federal, and municipal - as adjectives, while slipping in "federally, provincially, and municipally" when referring to Canadian tax collection ("[Policing in Canada v. Policing in the US](https://online.wlu.ca/news/2017/01/03/policing-canada-vs-policing-usa)").

So you would be stuck saying something was *state taxable* ([example](https://www.dla.mil/Portals/104/Documents/Careers/20110324090942782.pdf)), *taxable by state* ([example](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1287582)), or *taxable at the state level*.

Comment: Agree.  I’d probably go with “taxable at the state level” myself.

Comment: The words "statutory", and "statutorily" are used in Britain to mean something governed by "statute", as opposed to Common Law. Clearly statute and state have a common root. I am wondering if US states enact "statutes"? The word long predates the modern "nation state", and is found in the bible - as a law enacted by God or by a sovereign.

Comment: @WS2, The words "statute" and "statutory" are known and (lightly) used in common American English.  The former is approximately synonymous with "law", which is generally the preferred word over here.  I suspect that many Americans' familiarity with "statutory" may be limited to the name of the criminal offense "statutory rape".  Usage in the specialized dialects of the courts and government is likely a bit broader.

Comment: @WS2, *statutorily* is of no help to the OP, because both the state governments and the federal one enact statutes; the distinction between the common law and the statutes is independent of the federal-state distinction.

Comment: All these points for not answering the question?

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, I'm afraid I can't be of much help. For in a European context, each of the "states" are in fact "nations" - so we speak of "European law" or "national law". So whilst product regulations are determined at European level, taxation is determined "nationally". So it seems that we need an adverb denoting European, while you ned one of "state".

Comment: In Common Law, the law comes from two sources: statutes (written law) and legal precedents (court cases won).

Comment: "So you would be stuck saying something was state taxable (example), taxable by state (example), or taxable at the state level." Federal : federally :: state : state (likely in prepositional phrase)

Comment: @Lambie, common law, by definition, is not statutory law, although it is true that in the common law **countries**, statutes are a source of the law, in addition to the common law itself. (This is all, however, a tangent going away from the question.)

Comment: @jsw29 I said there are two **sources** of common law. Case law and written law (statutes), Civil law regimes, on the other hand, only have written laws (statutes). Courts interpret statutes and also use previous cases (precedents), which are considered "the law" also.

Answer (score 5):

In American English and in the U.S., generally federally is to federal as state is to state level since there is no adverb for this meaning of the word state.

For example:

to be decided federally:

[to be decided federally](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTpJ7fzlqf8AFXE4thD8GyCagrnnQ%3A1577547647908&ei=f3cHXoaBN4Tt_QbgqaP4Aw&q=%22should%20be%20decided%20federally%22&oq=%22should%20be%20decided%20federally%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299l3.63369.67888..68201...1.0..0.140.1351.12j3......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i302i39j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j33i160.k-4SsVY3gAk&ved=0ahUKEwjGvK351tjmAhWEdt8KHeDUCD8Q4dUDCAs&uact=5)

VERSUS'

to be decided at state level

state-wise is slightly different. It just means: as regards or with regard to (the) states and it can't be used exactly like at (the) state level.

- Freedom of speech is federally protected by and in the U.S. Constitution.
- Freedom of speech is protected at state level in many states.

[to be decided at state level](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTUMZYLdgkh3A5eaWBYpN9wDPz2ow%3A1577547717009&ei=xXcHXpsbzsv9Buq5nrgE&q=%22should%20be%20decided%20at%20state%20level%22&oq=%22should%20be%20decided%20at%20state%20level%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i302i39.66639.69805..70138...1.0..0.106.1460.17j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i22i30j33i299.gkMUYisFIO4&ved=0ahUKEwjbkaea19jmAhXOZd8KHeqcB0cQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

-wise in English means in reference to the preceding noun:

state-wise, goverment-wise, construction-wise

with regard to a or the state, government or construction (building)

**It is not the adverb that matches federally.**

Answer (score 1):

The word Statal fits the question if you need an adjective.  But I can't find reference to the adverbial 'statally', as in 'taxable statally'.

Definition of statal:

> 1 often capitalized : of or relating to a state (as of the U.S. or India)
>
> : statal citizenship
>
> : the statal economy

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statal

Comment: This is one of those examples from a dictionary the use of which is quite dubious.

Comment: Yes; it gives a nicely increasing Google Ngram, but one that is negligible when compared with that of 'federal'. The word exists (if M-W has it, OED will have), but is so uncommon as to be best avoided except in rarefied circles.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The same sort of circles that would use "[materteral](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58383/is-there-a-feminine-equivalent-to-the-adjective-avuncular)" or "amicular" as a complement of "avuncular"?  ;)

Comment: @Spencer Now how would I know?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't know. I thought perhaps someone might.

Comment: @Spencer Perhaps I _should_ have included the:). But I prefer dry humour. _It's risky when people think you're being serious. And yes, I often am._ HNY:)

Answer (score 0):

I agree -- *statewise* is the best (and possibly only) option in that situation, if it must be a single word.

If you were to discuss taxes in a more global way, an argument could be made for using *provincially*, but that wouldn't apply when talking about countries such as the United States. *Statewise* is still your best option.

Comment: @vectory common definitions of *stateside* seem to refer to the continental United States in general, as opposed to government at the state level specifically.

Comment: Although *statewise* might be the best literal drop-in, it's not really the best option in general -- you would probably want to find a more conventional formulation like "taxable at the state level", "state taxable", "taxable by the state".

Comment: @MikeGraham I agree, I'd go with "taxable at the state level" myself, but the OP asked for a single word.

Comment: state-wise, with a dash is a no go here. "It was decided federally" is not "It was decided state-wise", the latter being ungrammatical and not having the same meaning at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of many cases where a noun has an equivalent adverb but fortunately nouns can be used as adjectives to modify other nouns or adjectives or to replace adverb phrases. Examples: state taxable, girl talk, man trap, boy choir, school rules, state mandated, animal control. Some nouns can be changed into adjectives: yearly taxes, monthly rent

Comment: Yes; Lambie and indeed OP themself have already suggested the use of 'state' as a premodifier: _state taxable_.